# How do nested for loops work in c#

Tags: c#, for-loop, nested-loops

I'm not sure how this code is compiled (using visual studio code just fyi)

```
int i,j;

for(i=0; i<=6; i++) {

    for (j=1; j<=7-i; j++) {

        Console.Write("*");

    }
    Console.Write("\n"); 
 }
```

My question is when the code is beginning to get compiled, the first  **for loop**   is tested and it will be true, then the nested  **for loop**  is then tested and it will be true so *"Console.Write(" * ");* is written. But then from here I do not understand what happens or why it happens. Does the compiler then run  *Console.Write(" \n ");*  or...

Comment: It will then execute the `j++` and do the `j<=7-i` test again and print the star until that condition is false.  Then it will write the newline and do the `i++` and check the `i<=6` condition and then run the inner loop as many times as needed and so on.

Comment: Side note: Make sure you understand difference between "compile" and "execute/run" as post potentially mixes these two up.

Comment: Why not just use the debugger to step through the code to see exactly what it does? (And code doesn't do anything when it's getting compiled except get compiled; you have to *execute* it before it can do anything. The difference is very important to understand.)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, thanks for informing me on that topic will surely look into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

variables change like this.

```
i = 0 : j changes from 0 to 7 ( 7- i, but i = 0)
i = 1 : j changes from 0 to 6 (7 - i, i = 1)
.
.
.
.
i = 6: j changes from 1 to 1 (7 - i, i = 6)
```

in each i-loop you're printing j-loop and a new line character.

```
|j-loop|i-loop|
|******|'\n'  |
```

So, you will get the output,

```
******* 
****** 
*****
****
***
**
*
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't understand a for-loop you can always reduce it to simpler statements:

```
for ( init ; condition; increment )
    body;
```

is just a shorter way of writing

```
init;
while (condition)
{
    body;
    increment;
}
```

So your loops

```
for(i=0; i<=6; i++) {
  for (j=1; j<=7-i; j++) {
    Console.Write("*");
  }
  Console.Write("\n"); 
}
```

is just a short way of writing

```
i = 0;
while (i <= 6)
{
  j = 1;
  while (j <= 7 - i)
  {
    Console.Write("*");
    j++;
  }
  Console.Write("\n");
  i++;
}
```

Is that more clear?

If that's still not clear, you can lower it further.

```
while(condition)
  body
```

is just a short way to write

```
START:
if (!condition)
  goto END;
body;
goto START;
END:
```

So your loops are just:

```
i = 0;
START_1:
if (!(i <= 6)) 
  goto END_1;
j = 1;
START_2:
if (!(j <= 7 - i)) 
  goto END_2;
Console.Write("*");
j++;
goto START_2;
END_2:
Console.Write("\n");
i++;
goto START_1;
END_1:
```

Is that now clear?

Answer (score 1):

I will not show you the output simply because your question  is not what the output is but how the `for` loop works.

Let's do this step by step. Here is some pseudo code:

```
for ( init; condition; increment )
{
      Console.Write("*");
}
```

1. The `init` is executed first and it is only done once when the loop is encountered. That's right only once for the `for` loop.
2. The `condition` is evaluated. If it is true the body is executed. So `Console.Write("*");` is executed.
3. The `increment` is executed.
4. The `condition` is evaluated again. If it is true the body is executed. So `Console.Write("*");` is executed.

Steps 3 and 4 are done until the `condition` is false. Once it is false the loop exits and the following line of code is executed.

In your question you have a loop and if the condition is true it starts another loop. This loop starts at 1 and if `i` is 0, it is subtracted from 7, 7 -  0 is 7, and since `j` is 0 and smaller than 7, it performs the body and prints a *. It keeps doing steps 3 and 4 and prints a * seven times. Then the condition is false so it jumps outside the inner loop and prints a new line.

Then step 3 and 4 are executed for the outer loop.

It keeps doing that until the condition in the outer loop evaluates to false.

Answer (score 0):

`i: 0`, `j: 1 to 7` print `*`, then print `\n`

`i: 1`, `j: 1 to 6` print `*`, then print `\n` 
and so on and on